# Link to nested resource is displaying the parent's id in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**view:**

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <b>Comment:</b>
    <%= comment.content %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Commenter</b>
    <%= link_to comment.user.username, comment.user %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Link</b>
    <%= link_to "Show Post Comment", [@post, :comment] %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**contoller:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end
```

etc...

**route:**

```
Sandbox3Devise::Application.routes.draw do         
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

etc...

If I click `<%= link_to "Show Post Comment", [@post, :comment] %>` of a post with id 48
I get this:

http://localhost:3000/posts/48/comments/48

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to link to a single comment, use

```
<%= link_to "Show Post Comment", [@post, comment] %>
```

`:comment` is a symbol, not a reference to `comment`.